# Almacenar fecha y hora en variable en un procedimiento almacenado MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de almacenar la fecha y hora actual del servidor en una variable, dentro de un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, solo que no lo consigo, lo anterior lo hago toda vez que en múltiples filas ejecutaré una condición relativa a la fecha y hora actual y sería una sobre carga hacer un select now() en cada fila.
Lo estoy intentado de la siguiente manera pero no se almacena, solo se muestra:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Cliente`@`%` PROCEDURE `TblEmpleados`()
BEGIN
select @mivariable := now();
END
```

Comment: Ya probaste **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()**

Answer (score 2):

Intenta;

```
DECLARE mi_variable;
SET mi_variable = SELECT NOW();
```

ya que según la documentación oficial no estas realizando la declaración de la variable correctamente, ni la asignación.

[Documentacion Oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo logré, primero hay que declarar la variable y luego mediante una consulta y el comando asignar el dato a la variable:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Cliente`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE mi_variable datetime;
select now() into mi_variable;
END
```